# Do Miranda's passive buffs apply to you when she is unconscious?

Tags: mass-effect-2

In Mass Effect 2, one of your team, Miranda, has a trait you can invest in that in addition to granting her moderate improvements to her health and damage also passively improves the health and weapon damage of the other party members. (It might also apply to herself additively or multiplicatively, I'm not sure on that point.)

This ability could be pretty valuable on tough sections of the game where companions are likely to "die" quickly and you don't want to spend the cooldown and/or medigel to revive them, instead fighting the enemies yourself. (Doubly true if you are a Soldier and use weapons almost exclusively for your damage.) This would only be valuable, of course, if Miranda's passive bonus works on your team even while she is "dead".

Do you (and your other party member) benefit from her passive while she is unconscious/"dead"?